# Full page coloured box

Tags: positioning, margins, minipage, adjustbox, colorbox

I would like to create a coloured box that fits the size of its container exactly. To start, I have attempted to create a box that is precisely the size of the page.

My first attempt used `\colorbox` together with `minipage`, which gave me a white stripe at the top of the page and an "overfull `\hbox`" warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0in}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\colorbox{green}{
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}
      Hello world!
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{document}
```

After some searching, I found the adjustbox package. This attempt no longer gives an overfull warning, but the white stripe at the top persists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0in}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
  \begin{adjustbox}{bgcolor=blue}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}
      Hello world!
    \end{minipage}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

I'm clearly missing something, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the remaining space at top of the page by issuing `\topskip0pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0in}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\topskip0pt     % <---

  \begin{adjustbox}{bgcolor=blue}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}
      Hello world!
    \end{minipage}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!